# Spring reactive log the response body when exception occur

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, webclient

Im new to spring reactive,
Implementation.
In the response of the api if the first name is "Justin" retry and while re trying must also log the response body and same goes to if there is error in response will retry.

Both scenario is retrying but the problem is, for both scenario the response is unable to be log inside the `doBeforeRetry`.

```
 public Mono<NameModel> methodWebClient(){

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

   Mono<NameModel> nameModel =  webClient
                .post()
                .uri(url)
                .headers(header -> header.addAll(httpHeaders))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(NameModel.class)
               .flatMap(checkResponse -> {
                        if (checkResponse.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase("Justin")){
                            log.info("Errors response custom{}",checkResponse);
                            return  Mono.error(new Exception()) ;
                        }else{
                            return Mono.just(checkResponse);
                        }
                    })
                .retryWhen(Retry
                   .backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                                .doBeforeRetry(signal -> {
                                    Throwable throwable = signal.failure().getCause();

                                    if (throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException) {
                                        WebClientResponseException webClientResponseException = (WebClientResponseException) throwable;
                                        String errorBody = webClientResponseException.getResponseBodyAsString();
                                        HttpStatus httpStatus = webClientResponseException.getStatusCode();
                                        log.info("response status {} response body{}", httpStatus, errorBody);
                                    }
                                    System.out.println("Retrying due to " + signal.failure().getLocalizedMessage());
                                })
                )

           .onErrorResume(errorMessage ->  Mono.error(new CustomErrorException("asas","asas","asas","asas")));

        return nameModel;
    }
```

log if firstname is "Justin" then retry

```
2023-04-08 23:42:33.566  INFO 19628 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] com.retryable.service.WebClientService   : Errors response customNameModel(firstName=Justin, lastName=Wayne)
Retrying due to null
2023-04-08 23:42:34.713  INFO 19628 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] com.retryable.service.WebClientService   : Errors response customNameModel(firstName=Justin, lastName=Wayne)
Retrying due to null
2023-04-08 23:42:37.052  INFO 19628 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] com.retryable.service.WebClientService   : Errors response customNameModel(firstName=Justin, lastName=Wayne)
Retrying due to null
2023-04-08 23:42:41.575  INFO 19628 --- [ctor-http-nio-6] com.retryable.service.WebClientService   : Errors response customNameModel(firstName=Justin, lastName=Wayne)
```

log when server is having Error in response like 500+ or 400+

```
Retrying due to 500 Internal Server Error from POST http://localhost:8081/name
Retrying due to 500 Internal Server Error from POST http://localhost:8081/name
Retrying due to 500 Internal Server Error from POST http://localhost:8081/name
```